# C# WMI Get query for service info throws generic error

Tags: c#, .net, service, wmi

I am trying to get the start up mode of a windows service with WMI.
At the beginning everything worked fine. But now I am always getting a generic error of 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject'.

My code looks like this:

```
     string wmiQuery = String.Format("Select StartMode from Win32_Service where Name= '{0}'", serviceName);
     try
     {
        ManagementObjectSearcher wmi = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);

        ManagementObjectCollection coll = wmi.Get();

        foreach (var service in coll) // throws the Exception!!!!
        {

        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
```

Stacktrace:

System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Exception on a MoveNext sounds like it might be a synchronization issue.
What if you lock on the collection's syncroot:

```
            lock (coll.SyncRoot)
            {
                foreach (var service in coll) 
                {
                    //do your stuff
                }
            }
```